# Explanation of ecological parameters with some model examples

Tags: ecology

I think an ecological parameter is:

> A variable, measurable property whose value is a determinant of the characteristics of an ecosystem.

From [eea.europa.eu](http://glossary.eea.europa.eu/terminology/terminology_sources_html)

But what could these parameters be? In other words, what are some examples of 'parameters'?

I assume they possibly vary with ecosystem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you not understand the definition you gave? Are you looking for examples?

Comment: @Remi.b Yeah, examples for a particular ecosystem.

Comment: For a particular ecosystem, a variable will take a value. Are you looking for a description of a random ecosystem?

Comment: Any ecosystem. I just want to know how it works. There's no information on internet. At least I found none.

Comment: So you are basically asking "What is the average temperature, soil acidity, rain intensity, average daytime, .... in the toundra (or in the savannah or in other ecosystem)?". You can find many of these descriptions on wikipedia.

Comment: No, I'm not. I wanted to know what these parameters could be (like the ones you have named) ? My previous comment is kind of misleading. I just want some of their names from an authentic reference or an expert user and I'll do the rest, find out how they work.i.e how they help determine the condition of an ecosystem.

Comment: Part of the confusion lies in the fact that *parameter* can be used both in a technical sense (parameter in an explicit theoretical model) and in a looser, general sense ("*...there are many parameters to consider when buying a car...*"). Note also that you shouldn't mix up ***parameter*** and ***variable*** (which is also done here in the comments), especially in statistical models. Technically, a *parameter* is a fixed value, used to define a model (model parameter), while *variables* are things that are measured (and allowed to vary) - short summary: http://www.bmj.com/content/318/7199/1667

Comment: @fileunderwater I'll read it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of ecological parameters:

- temperature
- yearly maximal temperature
- rain intensity
- Longest period without precipitation
- soil acidity
- salinity
- nitrogen pollutants
- average daytime
- maximal wind speed
- solar irradiance

You can just have a look at the description of any biome of interest on wikipedia to get an idea of what are the most common parameters used to describe biome. Precipitation, temperature and how their seasonality are very typical descriptors of an ecosystem.

Comment: Is it always related to the non-living components? Can there be something related to biotic components as well, like species diversity?

Comment: In the description of biome you typically assume some kind of equilibrium in the sense that the non-biotic environment is fixed and most fit species will assemble into the right communities. When making description of of te environment a specific individual experiences, then yes, biotic parameters are of great importance.

Comment: Nearly all ecological parameters (at least the ones I can think of) qualify for ecological factors.